# How to create a fake provisioning profile for using with CoronaSDK?

Tags: ios, coronasdk

I'm using Corona to create a game but to build the app for iOS I need to specify in Corona which provisioning profile to use (which I have to copy to their certain folder).

How do I create a fake ad hoc provisioning profile?

My device is jailbroken but I need provisioning profile on my device, even though it's JB, in order for corona to build on device.

An alternative would be to create for xcode device simulator and run it on device but when I make ipa from app generated by this method, I get "failed to install" when I try to sync it to my device.

I am running Mac OSX 10.7 with xCode 4.5.2

Answer (score 0):

There are no such thing.

Corona uses Apple official tools to build the stuff it needs, and the official tools check on Apple servers the provisioning profiles, you need to pay for Apple developer program and do it correctly, or stick with more hackish methods.

Also, when you build for simulator, it builds a x86 version of the app, it won't work ever in any iOS device (they use ARM), the simulator is not a emulator, and actually runs the app natively.